# Easiest way for a child object to inherit all of parent object's data in C++?

Tags: c++

I wanted to see if there is a way to set a child class object to inherit all the data from a parent class.

ex.

```
InventoryBook allBooks[20];
SoldBook child[0] = allBooks[0];
```

For context, I'm trying to write a program in C++ that keeps track of a hypothetical book store's inventory and I wanted to create a class that handles a sale transactions.

```
class BookData
{
protected:
    char bookTitle[51] = {},
         isbn[14] = {},
         author[31] = {},
         publisher[31] = {},
         dateAdded[11] = {};

public:
    void setTitle(char newTitle[]);
    void setISBN(char newISBN[]);
    void setAuthor(char newAuthor[]);
    void setPub(char newPub[]);

    char *getTitle();
    char *getISBN();
    char *getAuthor();
    char *getPub();
    char *getDateAdded();

    bool bookMatch(char[]);
};

class InventoryBook : public BookData
{

protected:
    int qtyOnHand;
    double wholesale,
        retail;

public:
    void setDateAdded(char newDate[]);
    void setQty(int newQty);
    void setWholesale(double newWhole);
    void setRetail(double newRetail);
    int isEmpty();
    void removeBook();
    void delBook();
    int getQty();
    double getWholesale();
    double getRetail();
};

class SoldBook : public InventoryBook
{
private:
    const double taxRate = 0.06;
    int qtySold;
    double tax = 0, subtotal = 0;
    static double total;

public:
    SoldBook calcTax()
    {
        this->tax = qtySold * retail * taxRate;
        return *this;
    }

    SoldBook calcSubtotal()
    {
        subtotal = (this->retail * qtySold) + tax;
        return *this;
    }

    void setQtySold(int qty)
    {
        this->qtySold = qty;
    }

    int getQtySold() 
    {
        return qtySold;
    }

    double getSubtotal()
    {
        return subtotal;
    }

    double getTotal()
    {
        return total;
    }
    InventoryBook getBook(InventoryBook book)
    {
        return book;
    }
};
```

I wanted a SoldBook object to inherit all the data from InventoryBook without having to go to the extra trouble of creating a function that accepts the parent object as arguments and sets them in the child class ( SoldBooks )

ex.

```
void converter(char[] title, char[] isbn, ...etc)
{
    this->bookTitle = title;
    this->isbn = isbn;
    etc...
}
```

Well I know how to do it the hard way but I just want the easiest way. Maybe something like

```
    saleBooks[0] = allBooks[0];
```

Comment: You need to give `SoldBook` a constructor that takes an `InventoryBook` as it's only argument. Then the code you've written above becomes legal.

Comment: Also, you should ask yourself if inheritance is the correct design for your use case. Do "SoldBook" and "InventoryBook" model a "is a" relationship? An alternative approach would be to have a book class that has a state. Then you can use inheritance to model different states, such as "in inventory" or "sold". Finally you write functions that model the state transitions, such as a sale.

Comment: If your class has a lot of setters, you are doing it wrong. (Unfortunately some OOP tutorials are doing it equally wrong). Go to your nearest bookstore. Pick up a book. Can you easily change its title or ISBN? If not, then `setTitle` and `setISBN` are probably a bad idea for your software too. The title is set when a book is created (in software: when its constructor is invoked), and never changes afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do a constuctor take in the parent and member initialize it

```
public:
    SoldBook(BookData bd)
      :bookTitle(bd.title),
      :isbn(bd.isbn),
      :etc(etc),...
    {}
```

then you can simply do

```
SoldBook soldBook = SoldBook(bd);
```

or create a vector for then

```
std::vector<SoldBook> soldBooks;
soldBooks.emplace_back(sb);
```

emplace back uses a constuctor call to avoid copying
and honestly i'd probably but the library into an unordered_map for easy key access